# Difference/sum in an array to check for the two numbers generated that result in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For clarity sake, this is what I mean. I want to look for the two least numbers in an array(sorted) that will generate a particular number. The steps go thus:

- Loop through the array and each time set a current value that other
  numbers will be deducted from.

  - Keep doing that till you find the numbers that match the problem and return them.

```
Example. I need two numbers that when subtracted from the array will give a result of 2. 
let givenArray = [1, 4, 8, 10];
The subtraction should go thus: 4 - 1 = 3(doesn't match); //continue
                                8 - 4 = 1(doesn't match);// continue
                                8 - 1 = 7(doesn't match); //continue
                                10 - 8 = 2(match found); //stop and return 8, 10.
```

**NOTE: This same array may contain a 6 and 8 or 8 and 10 that will both yield 2 but 6 and 8 should be returned instead. The way the array is generated isn't of much importance.**

*P.S: I eventually solved it yesterday but I won't mind other ideas on how to go about it*.

Comment: `let arrayA = [3,5]` will always have two elements?

Comment: @brk Yes it will

Comment: @Maaz Syed Adeeb I have edited the question, the former was a mistake.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the requirements. Perhaps you can add a few more example inputs/outputs. Also, to simplify the question, it seems like you can completely eliminate the first part--find the two smallest number in an array which either have a sum or difference equal to a given number.

Comment: The way you say the difference must be this `let result =Math.abs(arrayA[0] - arrayA[1]);`     You provided `result` different from what you said. If you always want to balance the array by adding something to one element.   So you want to get the combinations which yields this `result` from the second array, right?

Comment: @Shiv C Kushawah Yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: According to my above comment. Get this `result` value and run a loop through differnce of each of the two elements of arrayB and compare it with `result`.    If there's any problem with looping you can provide that code.

Comment: @Shiv C Kushawah I have restricted arrayB to contain only 4 elements and any two smallest numbers from that array can be the result.

Comment: do you have a source of the question? what are the four value of array b for?

Comment: @Nina Scholz I am attempting the weight balancing question and I am at the point where I have to use the difference in weights which I have termed arrayA to look for the least numbers that match in the other array which I have called arrayB. arrayB has been intentionally limited to have four values only.

Comment: @camelCase, please add another example and the result to the question, for me, the second use of the value `2` is a bit misleading. is it a value from the first part or another goven value?

Comment: @NinaScholz I will do that and explain the question again

Comment: @NinaScholz so sorry for the time taken but I have edited the question totally now.

Comment: are you sure about the question. as last week has shown, some other questions started with the same problem and it was part of a challenge.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes I am sure about the question. I just removed those parts that seemed confusing to the other contributors but **I have solved it** though. I just edited it for clarity since I said I would.

Comment: @NinaScholz Can you kindly share links to some of those questions you mentioned?

Comment: for example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55892608 (the real question behind this was how to get a fromatted result, but not how to get the result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution takes the advantage of a hash table and uses a single loop approach for getting the two values out of an array to balance two values.

> First, take the absolute delta of the two values of `arrayA` and take this for getting the values out of the greater array.
>
> Then reduce the greater array `arrayB` by checking if the needed value exist and if the sum is smaller then a previously found set.
>
> The argument for checking is build out of the absolute delta of `delta` and `v`, the actual value of the array or by taking the sum of `delta` and `v`.
>
> The last point, and to make this all working, the actual value `v` is included into the hash table, for a later look up.
>
> The result is either an array of two values, which balance the other two values or `undefined`, if no values are found.

```js
var arrayA = [3, 5],
    arrayB = [2, 9, 5, 4],
    delta = Math.abs(arrayA[0] - arrayA[1]),
    values = {},
    result = arrayB.reduce((r, v) => {
        function check(w) {
            if (!values[w] || r && r[0] + r[1] < v + w) return;
            r = [w, v];
        }
        check(Math.abs(delta - v));
        check(delta + v);
        values[v] = true;
        return r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I always knew reduce could do this but didn't know how. How I solved this is to set a current value( starting from index 1) to be subtracted from index 0 on the first loop and if not found, increase current value by 1 and do index 2 - index 1 and index - 0, continue like that till a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, but perhaps this is what you need:

```
let result = arrayA[1] - arrayA[0];

let i, j;
for (i = arrayB.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) { // Set the first value
    for (j = arrayB.length - 1; j >= 1; j--) { // Set the second value
        if (i !== j) {
            if (
                arrayB[i] - arrayB[j] === result // Check substraction
                || arrayB[i] + arrayB[j] === result // Check addition
            ) return [arrayB[i], arrayB[j]];
        }
    }
}
```