# How do I call this function successfully to return a value? JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to solve this code challenge on scale balancing. A Scale that contains two elements, the first being the two positive integer weights on a balance scale (left and right sides) and the second element being a list of available weights as positive integers.

For example, if a scale is `["[5, 9]", "[1, 2, 6, 7]"]`, then this means there is a balance scale with a weight of 5 on the left side and 9 on the right side. The scale can be balanced like this 2,6

**Conditions**

1. The first element of the scale can only contain 2 weights
2. It is possible to add two weights to only one side of the scale to balance it  
   3.If it is not possible to balance the scale then your program should return  "Scale Imbalanced"

I have been able to do console.log of the function with hardcoded values and it worked. Also, the function returns "scale imbalanced" if none of the numbers can balance. But I can't seem to call the function dynamically.

HTML

```
...
<input type="text" id="balance" required>
...
<input type="text" id="weights" required>

<div class="button" id="calculateWeight" onclick="balanceIt()"> 
<input type="submit" value="Calculate Weight"></div>
<div id="displayResult"></div>
```

I want to successfully call the ScaleBalancing function to return a string if it is called. When I try `` ScaleBalancing([`${[balance]}`, `${[weights]}`])) ``, it returns

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()

JavaScript

```
function ScaleBalancing(strArr) {
let balance = JSON.parse(strArr[0]);
let weight = JSON.parse(strArr[1]);

const one = balance[0]
const two = balance[1];


for (let i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
    let weighted = '' + weight[i];
    if (one + weight[i] === two || two + weight[i] === one) {
        //let weighted = '' + weight[i];
        return weighted;
    }
    for (let j = i + 1; j < weight.length; j++) {

        if (one + weight[i] + weight[j] === two ||
            two + weight[i] + weight[j] === one ||
            one + weight[i] === two + weight[j] ||
            two + weight[i] === one + weight[j]
        ) {
            let balancedScale = '' + weight[i] + ',' + weight[j];;
            return balancedScale;

        }
    }

}

return 'scale imbalanced';
}

var balanceIt = function() {
   let weights = document.getElementById("weights").value;
   let balance = document.getElementById("balance").value;
   const Scale = ScaleBalancing([`${[balance]}`, `${[weights]}`]);

 document.getElementById("displayResult").innerText = Scale;
  console.log(Scale);
  };

  document.getElementById("calculateWeight").onclick = balanceIt;
```

Comment: please add the link to the code challenge or the complete problem description.

Comment: Done.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

it didn't work for my either. what I did is define it from the javascript so I knew for sure that the method is defined before calling it.

I believe what happened is that the on click method is not on the same scope as the balanceIt method and that is why it's not recognised.

hope it helped you

```
var balanceIt = function() {
  let weights = document.getElementById("weights").value;
  let balance = document.getElementById("balance").value;
  let scale = ScaleBalancing([`${[balance]}`, `${[weights]}`]);

  document.getElementById("displayResult").innerText = scale;
};

document.getElementById("calculateWeight").onclick = balanceIt;
```

Comment: When I did this: let Scale = ScaleBalancing([`${[balance]}`, `${[weights]}`]); I got this in the console, Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Now i see.. i think the next answer will work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If your input is for example "1,2", then

```
`${[balance]}`
```

would result in just "1,2" which is not a proper JSON string.

What you want instead is probably (notice the different square bracket positions) :

```
ScaleBalancing([`[${balance}]`, `[${weights}]`]))
```